# Crash network_proxy_decrement_outstanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

In crashlitycs I have crash like below. I dont know what this method do:

```
network_proxy_decrement_outstanding
```

I find that this is method for network activity indicator, but Im not sure.

I search project for `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` and I find that is used in:
AFNetworking and Parse libraries.

I would be grateful for any help,
Thank You

```
0   libsystem_network.dylib 
network_proxy_decrement_outstanding + 14
1
libsystem_network.dylib 
tcp_connection_host_resolve_result + 1596
2
libsystem_dnssd.dylib   
CallbackWithError + 464
3
libsystem_dnssd.dylib   
DNSServiceProcessResult + 944
4
libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_client_callout + 16
5
libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 2052
6
libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_source_invoke + 288
7
libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_queue_drain + 2008
8
libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
9
libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
10
libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
11
libsystem_pthread.dylib 
_pthread_wqthread + 816
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib 
start_wqthread + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing this same crash. It's happening rarely, but consistently enough to have a lot of data on it.

- We are not using AFNetworking or Parse but have exactly the same stack trace.
- We are using NSURLSession.
- The crash is only occurring on iOS 8 (with enough data to effectively prove that it does not occur on iOS 9).

This leads me to believe that this bug is caused by some bad code that Apple has written and it looks like they fixed this in iOS 9. I don't know of any workaround to mitigate the number of crashes you get.